# iOS programming - Duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

operator class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface operator : NSObject {

int number;
}

@property int number;

@end

@implementation operator

- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    [self setNumber:0];
    }
    return self;
}

@synthesize number;
@end
```

main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "operator.m"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

id operator1 = [[operator alloc] init];
id operator2 = [[operator alloc] init];

[operator1 setNumber:10];
[operator2 setNumber:20];

int answer = [operator1 number] + [operator2 number];

printf("The answer is %d",answer);



NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
[pool release];
return retVal;
}
```

I get an error -> `ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_operator.number in /Volumes/Home/Desktop/testing/build/testing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testing.build/Objects-normal/i386/operator.o and /Volumes/Home/Desktop/testing/build/testing.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/testing.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o`

This is my very first time I program in ObjC. Am I doing something wrong?

I tried the "Clean all targets" fix that I found on google but did not help.

Comment: Same .m having two different target can also cause this issue. Check my answer please in case someone comes to this question looking for an answer.[Check my answer if that is a case.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24394570/818506)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

1. You should never `#import` an `.m` file into another file. You import the `.h` file, if it's needed.
2. You should not have code executing in `main` before you create the autorelease pool. That is going to cause problems sooner or later. In this case, you test code should probably go in `application:didFininshLaunching` instead.

Comment: @alexBrand: You're combining the @interface and @implementation for operator in the same file, and then importing the whole thing. Don't do that. Put them in operator.h and operator.m, and then #import only operator.h into main.m.

Comment: I imported the operator.h file and it works :). Thanks a lot. 
I also moved the autorelease pool to the beginning of the code.

Now, how do I go about using the application:didFinishLaunching?

Comment: Future me - next time do a search for `.m"`

Answer (score 3):

## Static library involved

I added a class that had exactly the same name as a class in the static library that I also used. So adding a prefix to the name of my class solved the problem.

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Comment: I had the same filename.m into the source code. Both were not duplicates, but simply the same filenames. I changed one and worked as DanSkeel suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Search from an .m file that you can be importing in any file. Some times it is hard to find it

Comment: too much repetetion of same answer at every question like this. Its not helping anymore

Comment: sorry it didn't help you.. It was my problem when I found this question, and then I shared the solution.. and of course is not helping anymore .. is from year 2011..

Answer (score 0):

For other users where the above solutions were not the case this was what was wrong with mine. I'm a lazy programmer so instead of rewriting all the code for a new page (UIView) I will often copy and paste a previous UIView's .m and .h files... In doing so I sometimes forget to change the name of the interface inside the .m and .h files that I copied (even if I change the file names)... This will cause this same problem as well. Good luck to everyone else this happened too!

Answer (score -1):

In my case, i found a double declaration on a .m file in my **Build Phases --> Compile Sources**.
Deleting the duplicate solved the problem for me.
Hope this helps.