# Duplicate Symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GCOAuth.OAuthParameters ShareKit and RestKit.

Tags: ios, xcode, restkit, sharekit, jsonkit

I am in a sticky situation where for the last couple of days I havent been able to progress with sharekit implementation because I am getting a duplicate symbol error with RestKit. I am running with iOS 5.1 and the latest version of xcode. I have both libraries installed as to the guidelines given. I dont understand how to remove references of this from ShareKit or RestKit without causing problems in one or the other. I really need some help on this one... Thanks.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GCOAuth.OAuthParameters in:
    /Users/josephboston/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prowd_Wallet-ezxvmeygcnwgtzehshsnnprpsjww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libShareKit.a(GCOAuth.o)
    /Users/josephboston/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prowd_Wallet-ezxvmeygcnwgtzehshsnnprpsjww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRestKit.a(GCOAuth.o)
```

[image: my project]

Comment: Same .m having two different target can also cause this issue. Check my answer please in case someone comes to this question looking for an answer.[Check my answer if that is a case.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24394570/818506)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because both frameworks are using a common third party framework. So Xcode is complaining about duplicate symbols. This blog, ["Avoiding duplicate symbol issues when using common utilities within a static library"](http://atastypixel.com/blog/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-issues-when-using-common-utilities-within-a-static-library/) is explaining a way to fix this.

Here is the solution mentioned there,

> I’m working on two projects right now that have static library
> products, to be given to other developers to use in their projects:
> Audiobus and The Amazing Audio Engine. In both cases, I’m making quite
> heavy use of my circular buffer code, TPCircularBuffer, which would
> result in duplicate symbol errors if the static library were linked
> with another project that used it.
>
> Use the preprocessor to rename the symbols automatically during the
> build phase.
>
> This is done by adding a series of -DOldSymbol=NewSymbol flags to the
> ‘Other C Flags’ build setting – like
> -DTPCircularBuffer=ABCircularBuffer, for instance.

[image]

Comment: ok I am a little bit confused by this one... Can you give me a more specific example? I am slow. Thanks.

Comment: Basically you need to open the static library Xcode project and in their build settings, you might have to do something similar to this for every duplicate symbols. I am sorry, but I cant verify this without having the actual code since I never faced this issue. Just saw this suggestion and thought of sharing it.

Comment: Just to clarify... ACB is a random choice of yours? just to change the name right?

Comment: Well, that blog is not mine, and I am guessing that "ACB" was just a random word he assigned. In his blog, he is mentioning assigning to `-DTPCircularBuffer=ABCircularBuffer`.

Comment: @jimbob, In case you feel the above answer is helpful, you can upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: its definitely very helpful

Answer (score 0):

GCOAuth is used in ShareKit by Evernote sdk only. So if you can live without Evernote sharer, quick workaround might be to remove evernote and evernote sdk from ShareKit, using [granular install](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Granular-install)